# Username display - Bug with Chrome and IE

Tags: bug, status-declined, google-chrome, internet-explorer

So I get that Dave Newton used a special font for his username:

[image]

It seems to have no problem with firefox, but on Chrome and Explorer when he answers or ask a question (not on his user page though), instead of his name I get something like ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349628/how-to-accept-multiple-types-in-java-annotation-parameter)):

[image]

I tried changing my encoding but couldn't get it right.

Is it a known bug?

Answer (score 3):

Oh look, that's me.

FWIW, I didn't have any issues across browsers under Linux or OS X. I used to have some issues on mobile, but haven't noticed either way for some time now.

That said, in the interests of allowing people to reply to my comments with the **@** tag, I changed it to be plain text, and encourage others to do the same.

*Hey, it keeps removing my leading "Hey".*